# Ubuntu 11.04 VM shows a black screen in VMware Player

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware-player

I have a Ubuntu Server 11.04 64 bit VM running on VMware Player 3.1.4 that only shows a black screen. No matter what I try, the screen remains black. The VM has worked the first time.

When I reset the machine, it shows the VMware loader and a flickering `_` for about a second. Then the screen turns black again.

VM settings:

```
Memory: 512MB
Processors: 1
HD: 20GB
CD: auto detect
Floppy: auto detect
Network adapter: NAT
USB controller: present
soundcard: auto detect
printer: present
display: auto detect
```

I just created a fresh VM and the same happens, so it seems that the problem is consistent.

Comment: Is this a fresh installation? Has it worked before? What are your virtual machine settings? Is anything mounted in the virtual disk drive? It'll be good to have more details.

Comment: I tried ubuntu desktop, that seems to work sofar?

Answer (score -1):

I doubt it might work. You may wish to have a look here:

> http://www.vmware.com/support/player30/doc/releasenotes_player3.html

Answer (score -1):

I've seen a similar behaviour when you suspend the host OS while running a VM and later awaken it. I know it sounds silly, but have you tried rebooting your PC?

Answer (score -1):

This type of behavior can occur if you install a 64 bit OS VM into a host environment that can only support 32 bit architecture VMs. Double check you VM/host environments. You can test this by installing (known good) 32 bit version of the same distro.

Answer (score -1):

Just corrected this problem with Debian 7.5 and enabling hardware acceleration in VMWare Player machine settings.